# Magento2 need to create the download link in custom module

Tags: magento, magento2

I have created the simple custom module in Magento2. Which show pages correctly now I need to create the link on that page which download the PDF file which is in module web folder.

> For Ex app\code\Magento\Hello\view\frontend\web\pdf\test.pdf

What should I do? DO I need to add the routing for new function if yes how I can do that currently my routing file is

> \app\code\Magento\Hello\etc\frontend\routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="hello" frontName="hello">
            <module name="Magento_Hello"/>
        </route>
    </router> 
</config>
```

rest of the files are simple module files with no modification.

Please let me know where I need to write the download code for the link

Thank you.

Comment: For answer please refer question on Magento stackexchange: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/118226/magento2-need-to-create-the-download-link-in-custom-module/118272#118272

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working for me

```
 namespace Namespace\ModuleName\Controller\ControllerName;

 use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
 class Download extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
 {
    protected $directory_list;
    protected $fileFactory;
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context, 
    DirectoryList $directory_list,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory) {
    $this->directory_list = $directory_list;
    $this->fileFactory = $fileFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
 }

public function execute()
{
  $file = $this->getRequest()->getParam('file');

  if(isset($file) && !empty($file)) {

    $pdf = \Zend_Pdf::load($this->directory_list->getPath(DirectoryList::MEDIA) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file);
    $fileName = test.pdf;
    $this->fileFactory->create(
    $fileName,
    str_replace('/Annot /Subtype /Link', '/Annot /Subtype /Link /Border[0 0 0]', $pdf->render()),
    \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::VAR_DIR,
    'application/pdf'
      );
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Variant 1

What about moving your `test.pdf` into `pub/media` directory and linking like this:

```
<a href="/pub/media/test.pdf">here</a>
```

But the `pub/media` directory should be gathered dynamically, refer also to : https://mage2.pro/t/topic/153

## Variant 2

If you want to keep assets in the module folder e.g. in `view/frontend/web/Test.pdf`, you could address the web directory in your phtml template  like this:

```
<?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl('Vendor_Modulename/Test.pdf'); ?>
```